# Help me prove $K(k) = \frac{1}{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)$ where $K(k) = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(k\sin{u})^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Hi this problem is posed in Sean M. Stewart's *How to Integrate It* book **pg.143**

$$K(k) = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(k\sin{u})^2}}$$ where $ 0 \leq k < 1$

Based on the substitution:

$$ \tan{u} = \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{k+k\cos{2\theta}} =\frac{\tan{\theta}}{k}  $$

Show that:

$$K(k) = \frac{1}{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)$$

$K(k) $ is some function defined in term of definite-integral called *complete elliptic integral* which is not easily computable, so attacking $K(k)$ gave no fruitful result.

Well then proceeding with substitution ( **It is easy to lose track as it  involved a lot of trigonometric manipulations** )

I reduced the integral into this form :
$$K(k) = k\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2{\theta}d\theta}{\sqrt{k^2 + \tan^2{\theta}}\sqrt{k^2 + \tan^2{\theta} - k^2\tan^2{\theta}}}$$

Using substitution : $\tan{\theta} = p$

$$K(k) = k\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{dp}{\sqrt{k^2 +p^2}\sqrt{k^2 +p^2 - (kp)^2}}$$

To my naive eyes this looked manageable but [WolframAlpha says otherwise.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281%2Fsqrt%28k%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%29%281%2Fsqrt%28k%5E2%2Bx%5E2-%28kx%29%5E2%29%29%20from%200%20to%20infinity)

Any hint or ideas on how to attack this problem?

I thought  the trig manipulations to find a more suitable form but in the I end up transform $\sin {u}$ term into $\tan{u}$ to use the given substitution

**EDIT:**  It has been suggested in commens that there is typo in the substituion(given in book) , it should be :

$$ \tan{u} = \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{k+\cos{2\theta}} $$

Comment: This is pretty standard. You should try it.

Comment: By the way there is a typo in your substitution. It should be $\tan u=\dfrac{\sin 2\theta}{k+\cos 2\theta}$.

Comment: Hints : first convert integral from $[0,\pi/2]$ to $[0,\pi]$ and then the interval $[0,\pi]$ of $u$ maps to $[0,\pi/2]$ of $\theta$.

Comment: AHHHHH I spent hours on it due to a typo :( . I can show you the screenshot of the book . Thanks for your hint I'll redo it  and maybe post a solution myself.

Comment: I have the full derivation on my blog, but I want you to try it yourself first. The calculation involved is a bit tedious. As to typo, books can have typo. Learn to live with it.

Comment: More specifically: this is a Landen transformation and the relevant Paramanand blog post is [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals.html).

Comment: Let $l=2\sqrt {k} /(1+k) $ and you can also start with integral $K(l) =\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-(l\sin\theta)^2}}$ and use the substitution $\sin\theta=((1+k) \sin u) /(1+k\sin^2u)$ and get back to $K(k) $

Comment: The substitution in last comment is given by another elliptic genius named Gauss

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution based on [Paramanand Singh's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh) hint:

> First convert integral from [0,π/2] to [0,π] and then the interval
> [0,π] of u maps to [0,π/2] of θ

Using the definite integral property :

$\int^{2a}_0 f(x) dx = 2\int^a_0 f(x)dx$  if $f(2a-x) = f(x)$

We change the limits to : Upper Limit $ = \pi$ and lower limit $= 0$ *which will allow us to use the substitution given in the book* **[** ***$$*** **]**

$$K(k) = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(k\sin{u})^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi}_0 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(k\sin{u})^2}} $$

As the substitution is in the form of $\tan u $ we will express the integrand in terms of $\tan u$

We arrive at :

$$\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi}_0 \frac{\sec{u}du}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2{u}-(k\tan{u})^2}} $$

Substituting : $\tan{u} = \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{k+\cos{2\theta}}$ **[** ***$$*** **]**

$$\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi}_0 \frac{(k+ \cos{2\theta})}{k\cos{2\theta} +1}\sec{u}du $$

Now,

$$\sec^2{u}du = \frac{2(k\cos{2\theta}+1)d\theta}{(k + cos{2\theta})} $$

Leading to a cleaner integral:

$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{d\theta}{(k+\cos{2\theta})\sec{u}}$$

As

$\sec u = \sqrt{1+ \tan^2{u}} = \frac{\sqrt{k^2 + 1 + 2k\cos{2\theta}}}{(k + \cos{2\theta})} = \frac{\sqrt{(k+1)^2 - 4k\sin^2{\theta}}}{(k + \cos{2\theta})} $

Integrand reduces to desired form:

$$ \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(k+1)^2-(2\sqrt{k} \sin{\theta})^2}} $$

I think it is trivial to take from here to the desired form :)

**[** ***$$*** **]** ***If you are coming here from the book, this problem passage had lot of minor typos, rely on this post as a reference.***

***For.eg***

> For this substitution it can be shown that the limits of integration
> change in the following manner. When u = $0$, $\theta$ = $0$, and when u =
> $\pi/2$, $\theta= \pi/2$

***This is incorrect***

Comment: I have fixed a minor typo and rest is fine. +1

Comment: Also have you noted that in the range $[0,\pi]$ $\tan u$ is discontinuous at $u=\pi/2$ and the substitution has a problem. The substitution as given by Landen is $\sin(2\theta-u)=k\sin u$ or $\theta=\dfrac{u+\arcsin (k\sin u) } {2}$ and you can see the mapping of interval $[0,\pi]$ of $u$ to $[0,\pi/2]$ of $\theta$. The form involving $\tan u$ is obtained after some algebra.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are on the right track. But you have to be aware that the completed elliptic integral of this type can be defined by any of three integrals:

$$
K(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}\ d\theta\\=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}\ dt\\
=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t^2)[(1+(1-k^2)t^2)}]}\ dt
$$

This is from K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer . Chapter 61 covers the Complete Elliptic Integrals. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hints=    make clever substitute
$$u=x+arctan(\frac{(1-k)tanx}{(1+k)})$$
$$then..u\rightarrow\pi;x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$u\rightarrow0;x\rightarrow0$$

Any others can you send s.m.Stewart's book pdf link

Answer (score 0):

Using Parseval's theorem and the expansion for $K(k)$ we have:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}K(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(2n)!(-k)^n}{2^{2n}n!^2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ke^{ix}}}}|^2dx \\=  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2k\cos{x}+k^2+1}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-4k\sin^2{x}+(k+1)^2}} \\=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)^2\sin^2{x}}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{K(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k})}{1+k}.$$
So: $$K(k)=\frac{1}{1+k}K(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}).$$
Where we have used $\cos{2x}=1-2\sin^2{x}$ in the fifth step.